# Magento discount based on Qty in stock

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I need to give discount based on qty in stock,below are my conditions

Suppose i have 50 qty in Stock
1. When user buys between 1 to 10 he will 5% discount.
2. When user buys between 11 to 25 he will 3% discount.
3. When user buys between 26 to 50 he will 2% discount.

I have tried using catalog rule and shopping rule but nothing workout.

Please suggest how i can achieve above goal.

Comment: Read about tier pricing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question suggests that you are looking to provide a discount based on the in stock quantity. But the description which you are detailing suggests it is simply bulk order discount you are trying to achieve.

**Tier Pricing / Bulk Order Discount**

To provide a bulk order discount you can achieve this by using the Tier Price in the product - simply edit this and set the price you want to charge for each quantity level.

Using this approach uses fully the magento default functionality.

**Discount Based on Available Stock**

Alternatively, if you are looking to provide a discount based on the amount that is in stock you would need to look into setting a custom price on the product as its being added to the cart.

An example of this is below - you'll need to observe the event of course in your module to trigger this.

```
public function checkout_cart_product_add_after(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        if ($item->getParentItem()) {
            $item = $item->getParentItem();
        }

        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

        $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);

        if($stock > 5) {

            $orgPrice = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();

            $item->setCustomPrice($orgPrice * 0.5);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($orgPrice);   
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you help out with where i have to integrate this module

Comment: Actually , we are using Advanced product extension.So we want discount on attributes.Suppose ,we have 50 red shirts

Comment: The $product will be able to provide you access to the attributes that are relevant to that particular product. I am not familiar with the Advanced product extension you are referring to so I am unable to comment on the specifics of that. It may already have an observer in place which you could extend for that functionality.